# unable to filter namewise

Tags: sql

The query below works fine but I'm unable to search vehicle_name. Like I want to search for vehicle name 31 but when I enter it searches all instead of 31 only. Please help

```
 SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,bilty_No
FROM harvesting H 
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON H.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID

UNION all

SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,Bilty_No
FROM Blade_Harvesting BH 
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON BH.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
SELECT     Vehicle_Name,
           Total_Weight,
           DATE,
           bilty_No
FROM      (SELECT      Vehicle_Name,
                       Total_Weight,
                       DATE,
                       bilty_No
           FROM        harvesting H 
           INNER JOIN  Vehicle V ON H.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID

           UNION ALL

           SELECT      Vehicle_Name,
                       Total_Weight,
                       DATE,
                       Bilty_No
           FROM        Blade_Harvesting BH 
           INNER JOIN  Vehicle V ON BH.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID 
           ) s
Where      s.Vehicle_ID = 31
```

Comment: and if i want to use vehicle name as parameter like its prompt me to enter vehicle name to search..how to do that?

Comment: @MohammadImran You can try using a stored procedure in that case. SP will let you define parameter(s). You can use the vehicle name as a parameter then.

Comment: how? i'm new one please send me query

Answer (score 0):

you have to put where condition to your both select statement

```
SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,bilty_No
FROM harvesting H 
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON H.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID
where Vehicle_Name like '31%'
UNION all

SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,Bilty_No
FROM Blade_Harvesting BH 
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON BH.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID 
where Vehicle_Name like '31%'
```

while sending Vehicle name AS parameter

```
 SELECT Vehicle_Name
        ,Total_Weight
        ,DATE
        ,bilty_No
    FROM harvesting H 
    INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
    ON H.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID
    where Vehicle_Name = @Vehicle_Name
    UNION all

    SELECT Vehicle_Name
        ,Total_Weight
        ,DATE
        ,Bilty_No
    FROM Blade_Harvesting BH 
    INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
    ON BH.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID 
    where Vehicle_Name = @Vehicle_Name
```

Comment: and if i want to use vehicle name as parameter like its prompt me to enter vehicle name to search..how to do that?

Comment: like... u are sending full vehicle name in parameter or the begining letters or some characters

Comment: Full vehicle name.

Comment: it says you 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Vehicle_Name".'

Comment: using stored procedure or inline query

Comment: Yes on sql server

Comment: do you know how to connect sql server with your application

Comment: yes i did...right now i want to use this store procedure in crystal reports to make report vehicle name wise thatswhy i want to use parameter in crystal report to select vehicle name

Comment: whats is ur sp name?